# Memory management: building sparse matrix by efficiently iterating through other sparse matrix

Tags: python, memory-management, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to build a pointwise mutual information matrix. I have a 60k by 60k scipy matrix of word co-occurrences, and I want to transform this into another sparse matrix where entry i,j corresponds to log( p(i,j) / p(i)*p(j) ), for words i and j. I remove positive values to get a PPMI matrix. I am looking for an efficient way to iterate through the first matrix to generate the second, without taking too much memory.

I tried using a copy of the first matrix and iterating on that, and building a new CSR matrix row by row, adding each new row using vstack on 2 sparse matrices. Both processes are killed due to memory errors. What is the best way to build this matrix, and then to save it to reuse it later?

```
from scipy.sparse import vstack
from scipy import sparse
if(inplace):
    for i in range(ctxt_matrix.shape[0]): #row-wise operation    
        #for each row (word vector), reweigh this in 3 steps:
        # 1. get the probability of this context, instead of the raw count (divide by total words)
        # 2. divide this probability by the probability of this row/context occurring together randomly (multiply entry
        #        for word all the other words, do element wise division)
        # 3. take the log of this division, and reassign the row to this.
        row_pmi = np.log(np.divide((ctxt_matrix[i].toarray().T/total_words),(word_probas*word_probas[i]))).T
        if(cutoff_0):
            row_pmi[row_pmi<0] = 0 #0 cutoff
        ctxt_matrix[i, :] = row_pmi
    print('PMI matrix building took:', time.time()-start)
    return ctxt_matrix

else:
    #same as above, but on a new matrix, using vstack.
    pmi_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((1, ctxt_matrix.shape[1]))
    for i in range(ctxt_matrix.shape[0]): #row-wise operation
        row_pmi = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.log(np.divide( ((ctxt_matrix[i].toarray().T)/total_words) , word_probas*word_probas[i] )).T)
        if(cutoff_0):
            row_pmi[row_pmi<0] = 0 #0 cutoff            
        pmi_matrix = scipy.vstack((pmi_matrix, row_pmi))
        del row_pmi
    print('PMI matrix building took:', time.time()-start)
    return pmi_matrix
```

TL;DR - I need to do a row-wise operation creating a sparse matrix by iterating over another one. Here's some simplified code for an idea of what i'm doing:

```
from scipy import sparse
import time
start = time.time()
ctxt_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(scipy.sparse.rand(5000, 5000))
for i in range(ctxt_matrix.shape[0]):   
    row_pmi = np.log(ctxt_matrix[i,:].toarray().T/500) #some row-wise operation on the other matrix
    row_pmi[row_pmi<0] = 0 # don't store negatives in memory
    ctxt_matrix[i,:] = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(row_pmi).T
    ctxt_matrix[i, :].eliminate_zeros()
print('PMI matrix building took:', time.time()-start)
```

Comment: `vstack` uses `bmat`, which joins the `coo` attributes of the blocks to create new matrix. I'd call `vstack` once on a list of matrices, not iteratively.

Comment: I quite follow what you do in the `row_pmi` calc.  It appears that it has the same sparsity (nonzero entry locations) as the original, otherwise you'd get efficiency warnings.  I wonder if this could be done with the `data` attribute of the `lil` format.

Comment: It would help if you set up a small test case.  It wouldn't test the memory limits, but would make it easier to test and suggest alternative methods.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can use a list of matrices - a list of 64k 1x64k matrices would give me a memory error, I think. For the row_pmi, word_probas are a 1x64k np array of the probability of each word: word_probas[i] = p(i). For the top, ctxt_matrix[i]/total_words = p(i,j) for all entries j in row i.

Comment: I added a simplified test case that anyone can work with

Comment: Your test case is not runnable.

Comment: i updated the code with what i'm currently trying (eliminate zeros hopefully uses less memory).

Comment: `sparse.random` produces values in the (0,1) range, so the resulting `log` will all be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some variations on your code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import vstack
from scipy import sparse

n, m = 10, 50000
source = sparse.random(n,m, 0.2, format='csr')*5000
print(repr(source))

ctxt_matrix = source.copy()
for i in range(ctxt_matrix.shape[0]):
    print(ctxt_matrix[i,:].nnz, end=' ')
    row_pmi = np.log(ctxt_matrix[i,:].toarray().T/500) #some row-wise operation on the other matrix
    row_pmi[row_pmi<0] = 0 # don't store negatives in memory
    temp = sparse.csr_matrix(row_pmi).T
    print(temp.nnz)
    ctxt_matrix[i,:] = temp
ctxt_matrix.eliminate_zeros()
print(repr(ctxt_matrix))

print('\nrow lil')
ctxt_matrix = source.tolil()
for i in range(ctxt_matrix.shape[0]):
    print(ctxt_matrix[i,:].nnz, end=' ')
    row_pmi = np.log(ctxt_matrix[i,:].toarray().T/500) #some row-wise operation on the other matrix
    row_pmi[row_pmi<0] = 0 # don't store negatives in memory
    temp = sparse.lil_matrix(row_pmi).T
    print(temp.nnz)
    ctxt_matrix[i,:] = temp
print(repr(ctxt_matrix))

print('\nrow lil data')
ctxt_matrix = source.tolil()
for i in range(ctxt_matrix.shape[0]):
    data = np.array(ctxt_matrix.data[i])
    print(len(data))
    data = np.log(data/500) #some row-wise operation on the other matrix
    data[data<0] = 0 # don't store negatives in memory
    ctxt_matrix.data[i][:] = data
#print(repr(ctxt_matrix))
ctxt_matrix = ctxt_matrix.tocsr()
ctxt_matrix.eliminate_zeros()
print(repr(ctxt_matrix))

print('\nwhole csr data')
ctxt_matrix = source.copy()
data = ctxt_matrix.data
data = np.log(data/500)
data[data<0] = 0
ctxt_matrix.data[:] = data
ctxt_matrix.eliminate_zeros()
print(repr(ctxt_matrix))
```

results

```
1407:~/mypy$ python3 stack47615473.py 
<10x50000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
stack47615473.py:12: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  row_pmi = np.log(ctxt_matrix[i,:].toarray().T/500) #some row-wise operation on the other matrix
10069 9081
9931 8943
10159 9134
10069 9043
9940 8924
9961 9009
9941 8939
9935 8923
9943 8983
10052 9072
<10x50000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 90051 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

row lil
stack47615473.py:24: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  row_pmi = np.log(ctxt_matrix[i,:].toarray().T/500) #some row-wise operation on the other matrix
10069 9081
9931 8943
10159 9134
10069 9043
9940 8924
9961 9009
9941 8939
9935 8923
9943 8983
10052 9072
<10x50000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 90051 stored elements in LInked List format>

row lil data
10069
9931
10159
10069
9940
9961
9941
9935
9943
10052
<10x50000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 90051 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

whole csr data
<10x50000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 90051 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The `lil row` iteration is slower than the `csr` one.

The `lil` and `csr` data operations are virtually instantaneous.

There is also a way of iterating directly on the `data` of the `csr` format.  That requires indexing it with values from the `indptr` attribute.  That's been discussed in previous SO questions (could look one up.)

`csr` row iteration is kind of slow because it has to construct a new `csr` matrix each time.  The `toarray` step is a bit slow.  If you can operate just on the nonzero `data` values of a row or a matrix, it is faster.

This doesn't address the high memory use.  I'd expect the inplace changes to the matrix to use less memory, while the repeated `vstack` to use a lot.  I wonder, is the matrix so large, that simply constructing a copy of it produces a memory error?

Comment: For future readers: I ended up using bits of his code above, but the most efficient way was iterating through the individual elements of the matrix instead of row-wise, using a,b,c in zip(matrix.row, matrix.col, matrix.data)